# changing jdk in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, java

I am trying to update my eclipse to work with a jdk and not a jre. 
I followed the instruction in this forum , also search google for answers but for some reason it still don't work.

I try'ed going to preferences ->java->install jre's , removing the old jre from there and using the path for the jdk.

also try'ed going to project properties -> java build path -> jre system libraries -> edit-> workspace default jre.it also says there i'm using jdk.

I even try'ed adding to the ini file the next path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe

but when i try'ed deploying my program to app engine i get the next message :
Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

my eclipse version is juno 4.2 and my jdk  version is 1.6.0_31
I don't know what else i need to change. I even uninstall my older jre from my computer but eclipse still don't work with the jdk ( although it recognize it )

I'm out of idea's ... anyone could help me please ??

this is my ini file :

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar          
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
    -vm
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin

thanks for the help
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to change JVM Eclipse itself should run on, the right place for that is eclipse.ini. Here are instructions on how to specify that: [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Common mistakes are specifying `-vm` parameter name and the value in one line, or missing '`-vm`', or misplacing it. Also, pay attention to `-vm` format on different OSes.

**EDIT** (after .ini file published): your -vm option comes after -vmargs, which is wrong (both lines are treated as VM args). The correct parameter placement in your .ini file would look like this:

```
...
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: allready try'ed that . It does'nt work. I double checked the format for windows but nothing has change. I still get the same message

Comment: You can double check your configuration in Eclipse: Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details (button) -> Configuration (tab). In my case it shows something like "-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll". In fact, I noticed that in my eclipse.ini I have: -vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/bin

Comment: I changed the ini file so it  will show:

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin

Comment: in my case it shows: -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
but a few lines under it i have this line :
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin

Comment: Do you have line brake after -vm parameter? Configuration properties show that something is definitely wrong, and Eclipse obviously uses JRE6 JVM. Could you post eclipse.ini in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Below you can find my eclipse ini where I set a dedicated JDK via

```
-vm C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaw.exe
```

Have a look at the section "Specifiying the Java Virtual Machine" in the [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm&cp=0_3_0).

Quote: 
*Tip: It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify which Java VM to use when running Eclipse. This is achieved with the "-vm" command line argument as illustrated above. If you don't use "-vm", Eclipse will look on the O/S path. When you install other Java-based products, they may change your path and could result in a different Java VM being used when you next launch Eclipse.*

---

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaw.exe
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.retrieve.readTimeout=999999
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: You should accept the answer from @Arturs Licis in this case :-)

Comment: I did it allready. I don't know why it seems like I don't. I even vote for the answer being useful.

Comment: worth saying that in linux is `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin` instead of `C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaw.exe`

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me.  I eventually just removed the "jre7" directory and, presto-chango, Eclipse started using the JDK that was installed next to it.