# Google app engine project deployment error with java sdk

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a google app engine project. First i run that with a servlet and worked fine. now i add a .jsp file and then get a error

> Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
>   See the deployment console for more details
>   Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
>   I couldn't fix that.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDK is required to compile your JSP files. To fix your problem, you will need to use a JDK instead of a JRE for your Eclipse.

You should do the following:

- Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs. Make sure that you point to a JDK here and not JRE.

The above should address your problem. Restart Eclipse - just in case. If not, do the following:

- If your Eclipse is still not able to take that setting, you will need to specify the JDK in the `eclipse.ini` file in the `-vm` arguments. Check this answer if you have problems setting it up in the `eclipse.ini` file : [changing jdk in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913019/changing-jdk-in-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything and for me the problem was moreover. I deleted the file "error.jsp" from my project and it worked